# Compiling Java in Cmd and Running it

Tags: java, compiler-construction, cmd

When I try to run compiled .class java program with this command

```
java main.class
```

I get this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class main.class
```

When I compile the program with

```
javac main.java
```

It compiles nicely with no errors and gives me a .class file

What am I doing wrong?

I tried editing system variables to no avail.

Comment: Run `java main`. You don't want the `.class`.

Comment: Thanks, That solved everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply write this to run the program:-

```
java main
```

Remove the `.class`

Comment: Also check this doc for more help:- http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html

Answer (score 3):

When you run the `java` command it expects the fully qualified name of a class that has a main method (application entry point) not a class file name.

So it should be

```
java Main
```

Where `Main` is the fully qualified name of a class of the same name, residing in the default package in this case.

You may want to take a look at the documentation of the [java command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Answer (score 0):

let me explain you from very basic

.class files are created when you compile a .java file

javac is a command to compile a java code i.e. .java file

whereas java requires precompiled files. that can me a "NAME" of a class which has main method in it or it can be an entire .jar file.

*`so in your case the command which you are looking for is "java main".`*